# Snap app(s) NOT "integrated" into operating system

Tags: unity, snap

I have installed two `snap` apps: **Gitter** and **KeePassXC**:

```
gorre@uplink:~$ sudo snap install gitter-desktop
...
gorre@uplink:~$ sudo snap install keepassxc
```

Now when I do `snap list` I can see they are indeed installed:

```
gorre@uplink:~$ snap list
Name            Version    Rev   Developer       Notes
core            16-2.29.3  3440  canonical       core
gitter-desktop  3.1.0      9     snapcrafters    -
keepassxc       2.2.2      26    keepassxreboot  -
```

The issue is: they don't appear in the Ubuntu's Dash, so I have to go to a terminal and execute the app from there, but I do really like to see them "integrated" (to name it somehow) in the operating system...if there is a way.

I'm running: `Linux uplink 4.10.0-40-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:37:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be integrated. They certainly are here on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. Sometimes Unity needs a nudge to get it to refresh desktop files that have been installed. This command may do that for you.

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Alternatively, logout and log back in again.

Comment: I didn't know about that little `update-desktop-database`. That did the trick ;) ...thanks!